# needs help to check slight difference result of integration

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

I check my answer but i found myself wrong.
Here is the problem:

$$\int_0^
{1.8} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1+x)}dx$$.

substitute $ u = \sqrt{x} ,\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}= 2du$

$$\int_0^{1.8} \frac{2du}{(1+u^2)}du$$

using arc tangent subs

$2 \arctan (\sqrt{x})$ then i plug the suitable number and ignore zero since, $ \arctan (0) = 0 $. and here what's happen when i check using calculator , it's may seems trivial but this is supposed definite integral  , so can someone explain whats wrong here?[image]

Comment: But the upper limit is $1.58$ or $1.8$?

Comment: i'm sorry i'll edit the bound

Comment: Both the results match up to 7 places after decimal. It is very good, the numerical quadrature formulas (methods) are often not most accurate.

Comment: when you substitute you have to change the bounds.

Comment: The value of  https://www.integral-calculator.com   is 1.860548028230944

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc i just mere student so i would really glad if you explain what do you mean by that

Comment: Doesn't affect your answer but you forgot to change bounds for the $u$-sub

Comment: @EmilioNovati i am using desmos , but i don't even understand why there such difference between two i'm checking my input and sure that's nothing wrongs there...

Comment: And Wolfram, for the $2 \tan^{-1}(\sqrt{1.8}$ is 1.860548028230944090175527346818880046818888005444901980210...

Comment: @RhysHughes as you can see i bring back $u$ in term of $x$

Comment: @pikarin-g I know, that's why I said it doesn't affect your answer. It's just an error that could confuse someone trying to dissect your work, since $$\int_0^{1.8}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x(1+x)}\neq\int_0^{1.8}\frac{2 dx}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: @pikrin-g you may see my Answer posted now.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the simple integral
$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\pi/4$$
The value of $\pi/4=0.7853981633974483...$, whereas mathematica's NIntegrate gives  a value of 0.785398163397447...   which matches with the most accurate (analytic) result of $\pi/4$ but only up to 14 places after decimal. Numerical methods are supposed to be only approximate. One method can be more of less accurate than another.

Some numerical methods are Trapezoidal Rule, Riemann sum  and Gaussian quadrature. See

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration

Comment: thank you , that's really helpful for reference

Answer (score 0):

My hypothesis for this is that Desmos as a graphing calculator uses a very high-accuracy numerical method for calculating the integral, and so their value for the integral is very slightly off.

Your $2\tan^{-1}{(1.8)}$ is definitely correct.